# how to upload 3gp video from local system/server into ckeditor??

Tags: video, upload, ckeditor

I want to upload video into my ckeditor. I got one plugin  available in this link http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/HTML5-Video but it supports only three MP4, WebM, and Ogg format.

I needed some more format like 3gp,avi,mov .

can anybody help me .

Thanks!